# How to convert a string to rune?

Tags: string, go, character-encoding, rune

Here is my code snippet:

```
var converter = map[rune]rune {//some data}

sample := "⌘こんにちは"

var tmp string

for _, runeValue := range sample {
        fmt.Printf("%+q", runeValue)
        tmp = fmt.Sprintf("%+q", runeValue)
    }
```

The output of `fmt.Printf("%+q", runeValue)` is:

```
'\u2318'
'\u3053'
'\u3093'
'\u306b'
'\u3061'
'\u306f'
```

These value are literally rune but as the return type of `Sprintf` is string, I cannot use it in my map which is `[rune]rune`.
I was wondering how can I convert string to rune, or in other words how can I handle this problem?

Comment: `[]rune(sample)` ? like in https://play.golang.org/p/ISPOEvSzFQW

Comment: A `string` is not a `rune`, it may contain multiple `rune`s. The `for range` iterates over its runes, or you may use a conversion like `[]rune(sample)` to get all runes of a `string` as a slice. What is your question exactly?

Comment: thanks @mh-cbon. I don't want to just print them on the console, but I want to use the values in my map.

Comment: Thanks @icza, you know i want to map some rune values to another rune values. Thus by using `range` over a string, I want to take each `rune` and use it in my map to find the corresponding `rune`. btw, I am trying to implement a character encoding

Comment: @icze, but my problem is how to take that rune. By using Rob pike's advice in [here](https://blog.golang.org/strings), I used `"%+q"` to take each rune but `Sprintf` returns as a string. I was wondering if there is another way which I can use `"%+q"` and returns as a rune

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/strings

Comment: Thanks @Volker, But I have studied Rob Pike's advice as I mentioned in previous comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `string` is not a single `rune`, it may contain multiple `runes`. You may use a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert a `string` to a `[]runes` containing all its runes like `[]rune(sample)`.

The `for range` iterates over the runes of a `string`, so in your example `runeValue` is of type `rune`, you may use it in your `converter` map, e.g.:

```
var converter = map[rune]rune{}
sample := "⌘こんにちは"
for _, runeValue := range sample {
    converter[runeValue] = runeValue
}
fmt.Println(converter)
```

But since `rune` is an alias for `int32`, printing the above `converter` map will print integer numbers, output will be:

```
map[8984:8984 12371:12371 12385:12385 12395:12395 12399:12399 12435:12435]
```

If you want to print characters, use the `%c` verb of [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf):

```
fmt.Printf("%c\n", converter)
```

Which will output:

```
map[⌘:⌘ こ:こ ち:ち に:に は:は ん:ん]
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1O2hH3SnPFv).

If you want to replace (switch) certain runes in a `string`, use the [`strings.Map()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map) function, for example:

```
sample := "⌘こんにちは"

result := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if r == '⌘' {
        return 'a'
    }
    if r == 'こ' {
        return 'b'
    }
    return r
}, sample)

fmt.Println(result)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w2CTVJu9jgL)):

```
abんにちは
```

If you want the replacements defined by a `converter` map:

```
var converter = map[rune]rune{
    '⌘': 'a',
    'こ': 'b',
}
sample := "⌘こんにちは"

result := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if c, ok := converter[r]; ok {
        return c
    }
    return r
}, sample)

fmt.Println(result)
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ra-skPc0s_3).

Answer (score 10):

Convert string to rune slice:

`runeArray := []rune("пример")`